Como inserto los datos en un tigger update ya que me sale error
previamente he creado una tabla madre con la siguiente información
CREATE TABLE ubicaciones (
id_ubicacion int(11)  not null primary key,
direccion varchar(40) not null,
codigo_postal varchar(12) not null,
ciudad varchar(30) not null,
estado_provincia varchar(25) not null,
id_pais varchar(2) not null,
foreign key (id_pais) references paises(id_pais)
ON DELETE CASCADE
on update cascade
);

y también he creado una subtabla donde se guardaran las actualizaciones de los datos:
create table paises_actualizados (
anterior_id_pais varchar(2),
anterior_id_region int(11),
anterior_nombre_pais varchar(20),
f_modif date,
nuevo_id_pais varchar(2),
nuevo_id_region int(11),
nuevo_nombre_pais varchar(20),
usuario varchar(30)
);

he creado el trigger
delimiter //
create trigger Upda_paises
before update on paises
for each row
insert into paises_actualizados (anterior_id_pais, anterior_id_region, anterior_nombre_pais, nuevo_id_pais, nuevo_id_region, nuevo_nombre_pais, usuario, f_modif) 
value (old.id_pais, old.id_region, old.nombre_pais, new.id_pais, new.id_region, new.nombre_pais, current_user(), now());

pero al insertar la información para que el trigger se cumpla me da error, así lo he formulado
update bdrh_g54.paises_actualizados set id_pais=pe where nuevo_nombre_pais=peru;

ayuda por favor

Pulsa en [edit] y muestra como texto, con formato el error en cuestión. Además, reemplaza la etiqueta que colocaste en la pregunta por [mysql].

Quizá tu error es que estás haciendo un update paises_actualizados ... lo cual no tiene sentido. Observa la definición del trigger: create trigger Upda_paises before update on paises for each row insert into paises_actualizados ... O sea, paises_actualizados se actualiza automáticamente desde el trigger, el  cual a su vez se disparará cuando hagas un update paises .... Dicho eso, muestra cuál es el error y de paso agrega el create table de la tabla paises.
